# Count of unique values across all columns in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, count, apply

We have a data frame as below :

```
raw<-data.frame(v1=c("A","B","C","D"),v2=c(NA,"B","C","A"),v3=c(NA,"A",NA,"D"),v4=c(NA,"D",NA,NA))
```

I need a result data frame in the following format :

```
result<-data.frame(v1=c("A","B","C","D"), v2=c(3,2,2,3))
```

Used the following code to get the count across one particular column :

```
count_raw<-sqldf("SELECT DISTINCT(v1) AS V1, COUNT(v1) AS count FROM raw GROUP BY v1")
```

This would return count of unique values across an individual column.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your input data and output do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1`

```
cbind(raw[1], v2=apply(raw, 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))))
```

If it is for each column

```
sapply(raw, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])))
```

Or if we need the count based on all the columns,  convert to `matrix` and use the `table`

```
table(as.matrix(raw))
#  A B C D 
#  3 2 2 3
```

Comment: All the upvotes on @docendodiscimus's comments and zero upvotes on your answer might be because: **1**. Most think docendodiscimus is right, or more worrying option **2**. Most know about your childish behaviors on SO, and immediately assume you are wrong. Whatever the case, community is *telling* you to change.

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37983822/timeline (And as SO use multiple frontends, a lag in time is always possible between the frontends. Calling after someone because he posted the same solution is really a bad behavior)

Answer (score 12):

Use this

```
table(unlist(raw))
```

**Output**

```
A B C D 
3 2 2 3
```

For data frame type output wrap this with `as.data.frame.table`

```
as.data.frame.table(table(unlist(raw)))
```

**Output**

```
   Var1 Freq
1    A    3
2    B    2
3    C    2
4    D    3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a total count,

```
sapply(unique(raw[!is.na(raw)]), function(i) length(which(raw == i)))
#A B C D 
#3 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only character values in your dataframe as you've provided, you can unlist it and use `unique` or to count the freq, use `count`

```
> library(plyr)
> raw<-data.frame(v1=c("A","B","C","D"),v2=c(NA,"B","C","A"),v3=c(NA,"A",NA,"D"),v4=c(NA,"D",NA,NA))
> unique(unlist(raw))
[1] A    B    C    D    <NA>
Levels: A B C D
> count(unlist(raw))
     x freq
1    A    3
2    B    2
3    C    2
4    D    3
5 <NA>    6
```